# how to write a directions request for Google Maps Directions?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making an android app that uses the google maps directions services. I have finished almost all of the app but i have a problem with the directions request. I need that the request will give me a bus route and that there will be no transfers. I know i need to use the transit_mode bus ,and the transit_routing_preference fewer_transfers. but i dont know how to add it to the request. do i need to write &transit_mode=bus&transit_routing_preference=fewer_transfers& ?
i looked everywhere but i still dont know how to add those options to the request.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Directions API uses a simple [HTTP interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests), you're on the right track setting the `transit_mode=bus` and `transit_routing_preference=fewer_transfers`.  You'll also need to set `mode=transit` to activate transit mode.

I think the final URL you're looking for will look like:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Mountain%20View&destination=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway&mode=transit&transit_mode=bus&transit_routing_preference=fewer_transfers&key=YOUR_API_KEY`.

Note - The `transit_mode` and `transit_routing_preference` parameters will bias your results, but not guarantee the results will always be a bus route with 0 transfers.  You'll need to design your application to handle > 0 transfer bus routes.